# How to embed a shell and browser into a presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice-impress

I am responsible for demonstrating changes to our software every two weeks.  Since the software has both telnet and web interfaces, I think it would help the demo go more smoothly if I could embed a web browser and a telnet client or shell directly into presentation slides, like this:

[image: Shell embedded in presentation slide]

My current idea is to write extensions for LibreOffice to do it, but obviously I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I can help it.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?  I prefer PowerPoint 2007 or LibreOffice on Windows 7, but am open to suggestions for any software or OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the [LiveWeb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm) module will work for you. Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 download link [here](http://skp.mvps.org/downloads/livewebfor2007.zip).  2007 and 2003 [here](http://skp.mvps.org/downloads/lwsetup.exe).  Note: I've never personally used it, so I can't vouch for it. However, I've seen it in use, and it's quite slick.

I don't know of a way to embed a command line interface or terminal prompt into a presentation.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a browser-based solution for your shell. This answer on Stack Overflow has a couple suggestions, one javascript and another Flash-based:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445185/embed-telnet-control-in-webpage

Also, not exactly what you asked for, but rather than embedding your telnet shell in the presentation you could make the command prompt window "always on top" using a variety of tools. When you get to the point of your presentation for telnet, you could ALT + Tab to bring it up.

[CMDOW Commandline Window Utility](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) is a utility that allows windows to be listed, moved, resized, renamed, hidden/unhidden, disabled/enabled, minimized, maximized, restored, activated/inactivated, closed, killed and more. It has a /TOP switch that makes the specified window always on top. Perhaps you could use it to automatically trigger your telnet window to appear on top and at the position and size you wish at a certain point in the presentation.

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is a free command prompt replacement that has an option to make the window always on top.

JPSoftware's Take Command is a paid command prompt replacement that has an always on top option.